# Firebase cloud functions nested then writes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing an app which requires me to validate transactions and log them. Some of the code in my functions looks like this:

```
snapshot.after.ref.parent.parent.child('liquidAssets').set(newLiquidAssets).then( function(){
                snapshot.after.ref.parent.parent.child('transactions').push({
                timestamp: tinestampOfTransaction,
                transaction: transaction,
                stock: tickerSymbol,
                volume: sharesToBuy,
                price: currPrice
              }).then( function(){
                return 1;
              });
            });
```

I only want to add the transaction log after the set is completed. After the push I want to return 1. When uploading the code it says that it expects a catch or return here.

Comment: You'll want to put a `return` before `snapshot.after...` to ensure your `return 1` makes it all the way out of your Cloud Function.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you post the entire code of your function and not just a bit of it (this includes how you define the function, so we can see what type it is, and what else is going on).